# Generic xsd validation and xml for input and output pairing

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd

I've got a scenario for which I need to desgin in a more generic way.

I've a few xml messaging for different business-needs scenarios which has been paired. For example type1 input xml will be passed to the service and type1 output xml needs to genrated.

Complexity, I've a single xsd (more generic way) to validate all kind of input and output xml.

All my business fields (or information) will be enclosed with the tag's attribute value, so all type of xml could fit into this xml with basic requirement of some application specific tags.

> The real problem is, how will I ensure or pick the reponse type message
>   depends on the request xml?  Also if a few more input/output xml pairs are added
>   later, how can I ensure that they could easily be accommodatee by this transformer, without any code
>   change (or only minimal change in some property or database or some
>   representation format)?

Please suggest me some approach to work towards.
The real problem is the xsd is more generic and it doesn't care about the input and ouput xml pairing, it validates whether input or output xml is valid according to the business.

Help me out to proceed further in desgining such a generic and optimzied approach for the above logical/design problem.

Thanks in advance 
Awaiting reply.

Thanks and Regards
Krish

Answer (score 1):

When you define your XML at a very high level of abstraction, by making it very generic instead of specific to your task, it becomes difficult (and sometimes impossible) to make it enforce constraints that apply at a lower level of abstraction.  The constraints at the lower level of abstraction can be enforced only if the system knows about the details at that level of abstraction, and the vocabulary can be defined at a high level of abstraction only by glossing over those lower-level details.

This is not unique to XML; any system that allows you to choose your own level of abstraction will exhibit the same phenomenon.

I do not believe there is a generic solution to this class of problem.